# How To Show Modal AUTOMATICALLY with VueJS (+ Laravel)

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Basically I want my modal on website only appears on Saturday 06.00 PM to Sunday 06.00 PM AUTOMATICALLY.

How is that possible using vuejs (+ laravel)? Is it possible if I add some scripts in vuejs? If it is, then how? Because I have problem with it, I cannot find the exact solution for me in the internet.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
       showModal: false
    };
  },
  mounted(){
    let currentDate = new Date();
    if ((currentDate.getDay() == 0 && currentDate.getHours() < 18 ) 
            || (currentDate.getDay() == 6 && currentDate.getHours() > 18)) {
       this.showModal = true
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: how to call the script to the vue html?

Comment: @DrewsT wrap the code from arman in a function ```showModal()```, the function must be at the ```methods:{}``` of the vue component,let it return true when its Saturday 06.00 PM to Sunday 06.00 PM, then use v-if="showModal()" in the component or div which contains the modal.